# base64 favicon not working in explorer

Tags: html

I have tried to use a base 64 image as a favicon in my site and it works fine in chrome, but not in explorer.

Has anyone made this work in explorer or is it just not possible?

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Which version of IE?